# Mac OS X Wireless Keyboard Power Button

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I have done everything to trouble shoot my non-working keyboard. I've been using it a year and it is set up correctly There is supposed to be a power button? I sure can't find it!

Thanx!

Comment: Switched wifi to bluetooth - better match with keyboard tech that's used by the wireless keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

The power button is on the right hand side, it's part of the "tube" at the back and clearly marked with a power button symbol.

[image]

Did you check the batteries as well?

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: Checking the power button and replacing the batteries is what every person does first when such problems occur (IMHO). @Pam has been using this keyboard for a year! I'm sure he's smarter than that.

Comment: @Pam explicitly asked for the power button though... Oh well, never mind.

Comment: Did not read that part... That's weird! I'd undo my downvote if I could. Maybe, I should also take back the "he's/she's smarter than that". Lol

Comment: Hey, thank you! I'm in business. Ha. I thought I may have turned it off by mistake but could not find it anywhere. That's how long since I turned it off. Should have been doing that anyway. :) –

Answer (score 1):

Many people have experienced this problem. Often this was related to **bad contacts** inside the keyboard. This is a fix proposed by several people:

### Fix

> I resolved this by rolling some **soft household metal sponge** [...] into a small ball and dropping it
>   directly on the contact, then jamming in the batteries. Don't worry,
>   the case will close (my ball was about 75mm in diameter). [...] It is nevertheless important that the metal sponge **doesn't
>   touch the casing**, this could cause a shortcircuit.

source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1797139?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Hey, thank you! I'm in business. Ha. I thought I may have turned it off by mistake but could not find it anywhere. That's how long since I turned it off. Should have been doing that anyway. :)